# Woocommerce: edit customer's email address?

Tags: woocommerce

In a Woocommerce shop where there are no account registrations, how can I edit a customers email address that got entered wrong by the customer?  For that matter, how can I edit any of the information they put in?

When I go to Woocommerce/Customers, I can see the customers info but I can't edit any of the information.

I tried manually updating the "wp_wc_customer_lookup" table directly in mysql, but that failed to show any change on the woocommerce/customers page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First update

```
UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_email`='test@test.com' WHERE `user_email` = 'youroldtest@test.com'
```

And then update

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value` = 'test@test.com' WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_email' AND `meta_value` = = 'youroldtest@test.com'
```

Now the new email should appear

Comment: Thanks nbk but I said there are no account registrations so the wp_users table is empty.  After letting it sit for a while and going back and looking, it seems like there was a cache somewhere and the customer list now shows the correct email from my original update query.  I hard refreshed the browser so I don't think it was cached locally.  Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is in the original post, however there was a cache somewhere (still not sure where) that kept me from seeing it as updated:

Manually updating the "wp_wc_customer_lookup" table directly did the trick.